# How can I find the time difference in seconds between two dates in prolog?

Tags: datetime, prolog

How can I find the time difference in seconds between two dates in prolog?

datetime(2001,03,04,23,00,32).

datetime(2001,03,04,23,01,33).

timediff(D1,D2,Sec).

Sec=61

Answer (score 1):

SWI-Prolog offers several predicates that convert human-readable time representations into seconds from Epoch (at 1970-01-01). Having the time represented as a number of seconds turns the difference calculation into a simple subtraction operation. For example:

```
timediff(DateTime1, DateTime2, Sec) :-
        date_time_stamp(DateTime1, TimeStamp1),
        date_time_stamp(DateTime2, TimeStamp2),
        Sec is TimeStamp2 - TimeStamp1.
```

Usage:

```
?- timediff(date(2001, 03, 04, 23, 0, 32, 0, -, -),
            date(2001, 03, 04, 23, 1, 33, 0, -, -), Sec).
Sec = 61.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets a little awkward what with the months not being the same length and leap years having extra days.

To start you off, I'm going to give you a version of a predicate that will only take into account hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
timediff(time(Hours1, Minutes1, Seconds1), time(Hours2, Minutes2, Seconds2), Seconds) :-
    Seconds is Seconds1-Seconds2 + 60*(Minutes1-Minutes2 + 60*(Hours1-Hours2)).
```

If you could run convert_time/2 or convert_time/8 backwards, this process would be much easier, as it would allow you to use the operating system's time conversion routines instead of writing your own.

Comment: Which Prolog offers convert_time/2 and convert_time/8?

Comment: @Kaarel: SWI-Prolog for certain, though I see that GNU Prolog and Sicstus Prolog do not.

Comment: Right, yesterday I couldn't find it in SWI-Prolog because help(convert_time) didn't return anything. The reason is that convert_time has been deprecated, use format_time/3 and stamp_date_time/3 instead.